# Editing a User LocalStorage using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a webpage where I can perform CRUD functions using localStorage on AngularJS. So far I am able to ADD, DELETE users and save them to the localStorage.

But I am unable to save the edited user details in the localStorage. The "**$scope.selectUser = function (user)**" is the function I use for editing a user. 
Editing a user works, but they get erased on web page refresh. Which means the data of the edited user isn't getting stored. Looking for someone to guide me. Thanks in advance

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    console.log("in controller...");
    $scope.newUser = {};
    $scope.info = "";

    if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
        $scope.users = [
            { email: "John@yahoo.com", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
        ];
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    } else {
        $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }


    $scope.saveUser = function () { 
        console.log("Saving...");
        $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
        $scope.info = "New User Added Successfully!";
        $scope.newUser = {};
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        //localStorage.setItem("email", $scope.users);
    };

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
        $scope.clickedUser = user;
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    };
    $scope.editUser = function () {
        console.log($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser));
        // $scope.users.push($scope.editUser);
        $scope.users.push($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser), 1);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Edited Successfully!";
     }
    $scope.deleteUser = function () {
        console.log($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser));
        $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser), 1);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Deleted Successfully!";
        
    };        

    $scope.clearInfo = function () {
        $scope.info = "";
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>User Management- M&M</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <!--<link href="CSS/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="M&M" width="110" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="LoginPage.html">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active js-scroll-trigger" href="User_Mgmt.html">User Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="CompanyManagement.html">Company Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="ProductPage.html">Product Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="ShoppingCart_Group5_Team1.html">Shopping Cart</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="subhead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text" placeholder="Search Users" ng-model="searchUsers">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <hr>


            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUsers track by $index">
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.contact}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.role}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.company}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Edit</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Pop Up-ADD NEW USER Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">New User Registration</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="newUser.email">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="newUser.firstName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="newUser.lastName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact" ng-model="newUser.contact">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Role" ng-model="newUser.role">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Company</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Select Company" ng-model="newUser.company">
                                        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                                        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                                        <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
                                        <option value="LG">LG</option>
                                        <option value="OnePlus">OnePlus</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveUser()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pop Up-EDIT USER Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalEdit" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="clickedUser.email">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="clickedUser.firstName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="clickedUser.lastName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact" ng-model="clickedUser.contact">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Role" ng-model="clickedUser.role">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Company</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Select Company" ng-model="clickedUser.company">
                                        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                                        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                                        <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
                                        <option value="LG">LG</option>
                                        <option value="OnePlus">OnePlus</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="editUser()">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pop Up-DELETE USER Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Are You Sure?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5 style="color: red">You are going to delete the user "{{clickedUser.firstName}}"</h5>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="deleteUser()">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What function of controller is called after edit modal submit

Comment: @Vaibhav27, localStorage is not removed by page refresh. There must be something going in your code. Are you clearing the storage any time or on controller initialization resetting it or something.  Also the selectUser in the shown code  is not making any change to user value before putting it back to Storage.

Comment: @Vaibhav27, i may not be getting it right but you said "It just doesn't get saved in the storage after refresh".. Well your users value is reinitialized after refresh in controller so older user data is lost that is the reason you do not have edited users after refresh

Comment: @Vaibhav27 clickedUser is variable not a function.

Comment: @front_end_dev oh yeah I got misunderstood. Yeah there is no ng-click function in the submit button for editing a user. Can you please tell me what should be done?

Comment: @Vaibhav27 create a $scope.editUser function. Inside it update the $scope.users array and put it into localStorage.setItem

Comment: @front_end_dev I used this "$scope.user.push($scope.editUser)" in the editUser function and then localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users)); Its not working. :(

Comment: @Vaibhav27 Didn't get it. Update the Javascript itself so i have a look

Comment: @front_end_dev I was able to edit the user and save into the storage. But when I edit a user and click submit, 2 blank empty rows are also getting added in the bottom. I have updated the js file. Please check them.

Comment: @front_end_dev please check the code.

Comment: @Vaibhav27 I have put an answer. Update the `controller.js` code. Have a look into it. Make sure you remove the users key in localStorage `localStorage.removeItem('users')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes are done on the `controller.js` file

**Provide the `id` to each user object so they can be track efficiently without checking reference of object.**

```
 function parseData(input) {
        return input.reduce(function (o, i) {
            o.push(Object.assign({"id":Date.now()},i));
            return o;
        },[]);
    }

var initialData = [
            { email: "John@yahoo.com", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
        ];
        $scope.users = parseData(initialData);
```

**While selecting user create a new object instead of setting the reference of existing**

```
$scope.clickedUser = Object.assign({},user);
```

**While edit user iterate over the `users` object and update the edited user instead of setting the reference**

```
$scope.editUser = function () {
        $scope.users = $scope.users.reduce(function (o,user) {
           if(user.id === $scope.clickedUser.id){
               user = Object.assign(user,$scope.clickedUser);
           }
           o.push(user);
           return o;
        },[]);
        $scope.clickedUser = {};
        console.log("Users detail => ",$scope.users);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Edited Successfully!";
    };
```

Delete user method

```
 $scope.deleteUser = function () {
        $scope.users = $scope.users.reduce(function (o,user) {
            if(user.id !== $scope.clickedUser.id){
                o.push(user);
            }
            return o;
        },[]);
        $scope.clickedUser = {};
        console.log("Users detail => ",$scope.users);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Deleted Successfully!";
    };
```

Complete code for `controller.js` file

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    console.log("in controller...");
    $scope.newUser = {};
    $scope.clickedUser = {};
    $scope.info = "";

    function parseData(input) {
        return input.reduce(function (o, i) {
            o.push(Object.assign({"id":Date.now()},i));
            return o;
        },[]);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
        var initialData = [
            { email: "John@yahoo.com", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
        ];
        $scope.users = parseData(initialData);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    } else {
        $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }


    $scope.saveUser = function () {
        console.log("Saving...");
        $scope.users.push(Object.assign({"id":Date.now()},$scope.newUser));
        $scope.info = "New User Added Successfully!";
        $scope.newUser = {};
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    };

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
        $scope.clickedUser = Object.assign({},user);
    };

    $scope.editUser = function () {
        $scope.users = $scope.users.reduce(function (o,user) {
           if(user.id === $scope.clickedUser.id){
               user = Object.assign(user,$scope.clickedUser);
           }
           o.push(user);
           return o;
        },[]);
        $scope.clickedUser = {};
        console.log("Users detail => ",$scope.users);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Edited Successfully!";
    };

    $scope.deleteUser = function () {
        $scope.users = $scope.users.reduce(function (o,user) {
            if(user.id !== $scope.clickedUser.id){
                o.push(user);
            }
            return o;
        },[]);
        $scope.clickedUser = {};
        console.log("Users detail => ",$scope.users);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Deleted Successfully!";
    };

    $scope.clearInfo = function () {
        $scope.info = "";
    };
});
```